# keycloak, why does backend channels need a redirect url

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid

I try to integrate my Python app(backend client) into the Keycloak system using openid connect, why do I have to fill the `Valid Redirect URIs` field? From my understanding for OAuth 2.0, the backend channel just need to exchange the code for id and access tokens in the **[Authorization Code Flow](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#authorization-code-flow)** process

Why do we need a redirect URL here, shouldn't it only filled in the front end client?

Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client which receives the authorization code and the one which exchanges the code for tokens must be the same client - at least from the Authorization Server's point of view. Theoretically you can have separate applications which handle parts of the OAuth flow, but they must be using the same client ID.

Ideally, the redirect URI points to an endpoint exposed by your Python backend. After Keycloak (or any Authorization Server) finishes authentication and authorization, it will redirect the user to that endpoint together with the authorization code. This way the authorization code will go straight to the backend client, the frontend app will never have to handle it. By registering the URL you want to make sure that no one performs authorization using your client ID, but asks to send the code to another application.

Comment: Hi @Michai , how do i redirect to my fronend then? Let's assume I am trying to login, after entering my username and password keycloak will exchange authorization code and access token through the back channel right, but after the successful login I need to redirect to my frontend, how to do that??

Comment: When keycloak returns the authorization code to your backend it actually does that through a browser redirect. So, technically, the browser receives a 302 redirect from keycloak and sends a new request to your backend. The backend then performs the code exchange and should send a response to the browser's request. This is how your user ends up in the frontend app again. The response from your backend client should redirect the user back to the frontend app. It should also set some session cookies, so that the frontend app has an active session to your backend.

Answer (score 1):

We need it to restrict to what URL we are allowed to redirect to after a successful login. We do this to improve the security for your users, because it would be a big security problem if the provider could redirect to any URL after login.