# "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" Keycloak Setup

Tags: python, django, keycloak

I am setting up Keycloak with Django (just hosting it locally now) and this is the error I am getting. I have not found any helpful answers on stackoverflow yet.

[image: Keycloak setup error]

I have tried setting the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL_FAILURE variables in settings.py but that had no effect. The only redirect_uri setting I can find is in a package.

[image: Code snippet]

`redirect_uri` is listed in the query string parameters, but it is different than what I set in settings.py:

I also tried setting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to 'localhost:8000/oidccallback' and nothing changed. Setting POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL also did not change anything.

[image: redirect_uri in the query string parameters]

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061300/keycloak-why-does-backend-channels-need-a-redirect-url

Comment: @Corralien That setting is set up correctly.

Comment: @A_Quack What is the redirect_uri in query string parameter and what did you define in settings.py?

Comment: @Abhijeet My redirect_uri in the query string parameters is 'http://localhost:8000/oidccallback'. In settings.py, my redirect_uri is 'http://localhost:8000/'

Comment: Add http://localhost:8000/oidccallback url in your settings.py, it should work

Comment: @Abhijeet I tried that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Abhijeet There were errors in one of my plugins that caused the logout redirect to fail. I can now change the logout redirect url, but I still see the "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" error.

Comment: Try configuring Valid Redirect URI as `http://localhost:port/*` from keycloak admin console